# Quick create simple product doesn't inherit custom attributes

Tags: attributes, magento-1.8, configurable-product, inheritance

I set up a list of custom attributes in a configurable product, and I found that the quick create form is really handy to set up the simple associated products.

Problem: the simple products are not inheriting the custom attributes set on the parent configurable product.

Can this be automated, so that every custom attribute values in configurable parent product is set on its children simple products ?

Thanks.

#### Edit

I now realized that I do not intend to have configurable simple products appear as standalone products, so I presume I won't lose search functionality even when the attribute will be set only in the viewable parent product.

Nevertheless, I keep the question opened if it's a simple solution like attaching to an observer.

Comment: An observer might do the trick. You can trigger it on a product save event. This event will give you the configurable product and it's simple products (or at least the ID's)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue.

There was a rewrite of the `quickCreateAction` of class `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController` in my setup.

The original method first check for inherited attribute values from configurable product, then sets the request parameter attributes from the form.

My rewrite messed with that and now I fixed it.